# Constructors with inheritance not applicable

Tags: java, constructor

I am new to Java. I have been researching constructors, inheritance, arrays and abstract classes recently. I am trying to combine all of these concepts into code for practice.

I have an abstract base class called Person3, a subclass called Student1 and a subclass called Staff1. I also have a driver program.

I received errors about the Student1 and Staff1 constructors when compiling and would like some clarification because I am just not seeing the issues.

Can someone please explain in detail why these errors are occurring? Thanks!

Errors:

```
no suitable constructor found for Student1(String,Date,int,double,double)
                Student1 st = new Student1("Jack", new Date("May", 8, 1990), 00000001, 7.50, 7.00);
                              ^
    constructor Student1.Student1(Student1) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    constructor Student1.Student1(String[],Date[],int[],double[],double[]) is not applicable
      (actual argument String cannot be converted to String[] by method invocation conversion)
    constructor Student1.Student1() is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

no suitable constructor found for Staff1(String,Date,int,double,double,double)
                myPerson[1] = new Staff1("Will", new Date("July", 10, 1998), 00000002, 7.00, 8.00, 3900.00);
                              ^
    constructor Staff1.Staff1(Staff1) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    constructor Staff1.Staff1(String[],Date[],int[],double[],double[],double[]) is not applicable
      (actual argument String cannot be converted to String[] by method invocation conversion)
    constructor Staff1.Staff1() is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

Applicable code for Student1 class:

```
public class Student1 extends Person3
{
    private double [] wageRate;
    private double [] hours; 

    public Student1(){
        super( );
        for(int i = 0; i < wageRate.length; i++) {
            wageRate[i] = 0.00;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < hours.length; i++){
            hours[i] = 0.00;
        }
    }

    public Student1(String [] theName, Date [] theDate, int [] theSocial, double [] theWageRate, double [] theHours){
        super(theName, theDate, theSocial);
        if ((theWageRate != null) && (theHours != null)){
            wageRate = theWageRate;
            hours = theHours;
        }
        else{
             System.out.println("Fatal Error: creating an illegal hourly employee.");
             System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public Student1(Student1 originalObject)
    {
         super(originalObject);
         wageRate = originalObject.wageRate;
         hours = originalObject.hours;
    }
```

Applicable code for Staff1 class:

```
public class Staff1 extends Person3
{
    private double [] salary;

    public Staff1()
    {
        super( );
         for(int i = 0; i < salary.length; i++){
            salary[i]=0.00;
        }
    }

    public Staff1(String [] theName, Date [] theDate, int [] theSocial, double [] theWageRate, double [] theHours, double [] theSalary){
         super(theName, theDate, theSocial);
         if (theSalary != null)
             salary = theSalary;
         else
         {
             System.out.println("Fatal Error: Negative salary.");
             System.exit(0);
         }
    }

    public Staff1(Staff1 originalObject){
        super((Person3)originalObject);
         salary = originalObject.salary;
    }
```

Driver program attempts to the following and receives errors:

```
Student1 st= new Student1("Jack", new Date("May", 8, 1990), 00000001, 7.50, 7.00);
myPerson[1] = new Staff1("Will", new Date("July", 10, 1998), 00000002, 7.00, 8.00, 3900.00);
```

Comment: A constructor with this signature: `public Student1(String[], Date[], int[], double[], double[])` is different from a constructor with this signature: `public Student1(String, Date, int, double, double)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you aware of the fact that `Type[]` means "Array of `Type`"?

So according to these two constructor declarations:

```
public Student1(String [] theName, Date [] theDate, int [] theSocial, double [] theWageRate, double [] theHours)
```

```
public Staff1(String [] theName, Date [] theDate, int [] theSocial, double [] theWageRate, double [] theHours, double [] theSalary)
```

All arguments have to be arrays.
But from your error message, it is clear that you're passing plain values to the constructors.

Remove all the `[]` from the constructor declarations and you should be fine.

Or, if the arguments are actually supposed to all be arrays, you would have to call the constructors like this:

```
Student1 st = new Student1(new String[]{"Jack"}, new Date[]{new Date("May", 8, 1990)}, new int[]{1}, new double[]{7.50}, new double[]{7.00});
```

```
myPerson[1] = new Staff1(new String[]{"Will"}, new Date[]{new Date("July", 10, 1998)}, new int[]{2}, new double[]{7.00}, new double[]{8.00}, new double[]{3900.00});
```

Comment: Hello. But the variable values are suppose to be arrays. How can I create a student with arrays of objects instead perhaps?

Comment: @Justin Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I was trying to grasp. So to understand fully, I originally has two constructors that claimed to take in array values, but the driver program actually took in simple values causing the errors. So your update explained that calling the constructors require a new instantiation with the array and {} that contain the desired values. Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for your help and time. I appreciate it and look forward to learning more Java.

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor for students:

```
public Student1(String [] theName, Date [] theDate, int [] theSocial, double [] theWageRate, double [] theHours)
```

takes arrays as arguments. However when you initialize your student object:

```
new Student1("Jack", new Date("May", 8, 1990), 00000001, 7.50, 7.00);
```

You are not using arrays, just simple values. You either need to modify your constructor to take in single values, or you need to create a student with arrays of objects.

Comment: Hello. Can you please elaborate on what you mean by "create a student with arrays of objects"?

Comment: @Justin The arguments you pass to the `Student` constructor need to be arrays. Or the constructor must take plain values instead of arrays.

Comment: Sure. So.. since it sounds like you don't want to modify your constructor - which is fine. You need to pass array values. In order to do that you can do the following: `new Student1(new String[]{"Jack"}, new Date[] {(new Date("May", 8, 1990))}`, etc....

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor is taking in arrays as arguments. You would need to change it to:

```
public Student1(String theName, Date theDate, int theSocial, double theWageRate, double theHours)
```

To learn more about arrays, check out https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: Hello. But the variable values are suppose to be arrays. How can I create a student with arrays of objects instead perhaps?

Comment: If that's the case, then you need to change the arguments that you're passing through.

`Student1 st= new Student1("Jack", new Date("May", 8, 1990), 00000001, 7.50, 7.00);`

Notice how those are taking a single values rather than arrays. `"Jack" `is a `String` object but the constructor is asking for a `String` array. `"new Date(...)"` is a `Date` object but the constructor is asking for the array of Date objects. And so on and so forth.